# Laravel - Validar un $request que tiene un array con rules formrequest

Tags: laravel, validate

el request Viene con la forma:

```
$request = [
    id => x,
    nombre => 'yyy',
    detalle => [
       linea1=>dato1,
       lineas2=>datos2,
    ]
]
```

Mi pregunta es ¿como puedo validar las lineas del array detalle?

No tengo problemas con la validacion del primer nivel.

Comment: Como validas la primera parte? tenes algo de codigo para mostrar?

Answer (score 0):

ya lo logré.
Hay que validar (en el array rules()), con la forma:

'detalle.*.nombre' => 'required|string|min:1',

Gracias a todos igual.